# Searching gmail at google.com - strange things happen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been looking this days to the code (using google chrome and its Inspect element feature) of several pages in order to see what they are doing (javascript, css, html, etc...) and I've seen something strange when searching for [gmail](https://www.google.es/#q=gmail) at www.google.es (It's the same with www.google.com)

Just go to the link or search it yourselves and you'll see:

[image]

What is that line doing there? I already tried cleaning my monitor but it's not that ;)

I tried to look at the code in order to see if I could understand what is going on but I can't see anything strange:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: A software bug crawling across the page?

Comment: This is just a bunch of unicode modifier spam, nothing special going on.  [eeemo.net](https://eeemo.net/) can generate these.

Comment: Infected extensions?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945154/messed-up-characters-in-webpages-especially-social-media) is answer of your question.

Comment: There is a character ฏ๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a single unicode character ฏ๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎ which has an unicode entities of `\u0e0f\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e\u0e4e` 
Basically the diacritical mark (commonly used for accented letter) was added to the letter 26 times.

It has nothing to do with google itself, that character was in the meta tag of one of the sites it crawled and thus shown in the search result.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945154/messed-up-characters-in-webpages-especially-social-media) Alex posted, provides detailed explanation on this.